# What is the equivalent code in Flutter Dio/http compare to Axios 'withCredentials' in React for handling Cookie based authenticated requests?

Tags: flutter, cookies, axios, httprequest, dio

I am trying to send http requests to server which automatically detects whether the user is logged in or not by cookies. It works in React with Axios HTTP client by adding withCredentials to true and also works in Postman. But it returns 401 'Unauthorized' in Flutter with Dio while the same URL works with the above code of Axios in React. The backend developer said to pass 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true' in the header but it's returning the same result. I am attaching the React and Flutter code. Please help.
In React:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../lib/api-endpoints';

const request = axios.create({
     baseURL: BASE_URL, 
     headers: { 
         Accept: 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

 withCredentials: true,

});

export default request;
```

In Flutter when I send request with following code it returns 401 'Unauthorized' while same URL works with the above code of Axios in React.

```
var response = await Dio().post(
    BASE_URL,
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

For flutter you can add withCredentials in Dio like following but it will only work for browser:

```
import 'package:dhaka_eats/api/urls.dart';
import 'package:dio/adapter_browser.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class Api {
   static Dio dio() {
   BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
     connectTimeout: 10000,
     receiveTimeout: 5000,
     baseUrl: BASE_URL,
     headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     },
   );


    var _dio = Dio(options);
    var adapter = BrowserHttpClientAdapter();
    adapter.withCredentials = true;
    _dio.httpClientAdapter = adapter;
   return _dio;
  }
}
```

Now you can do HTTP request:

```
await Api.dio().post('/signin', data: payload);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe it this isn't documented anywhere, I've stumbled on a simpler solution on dio's github, you can just set it via `dio.options.extra['withCredentials'] = true;` as per https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/1f97653f6e0a54c69cd0649d92498d2b2fa2db4d/dio/lib/src/adapters/browser_adapter.dart#L34